# Datatable expressions for trigonmetric functions

Tags: c#, datatable

I am trying to create a data table with x and y values from a function that the user inputs. Later  I'll take these values and try to make them into gCode, but that's for later. Right now I can't find any information on how if even possible you can use .Expression in your column for a sin or cos function.

For context here is my code so far:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        DataTable table = MakeTable(-50,1,"sin(x)");
        DebugTable(table);
    }
    
    public static DataTable MakeTable(int startval,int step,string func)
    {
        DataTable table = new DataTable("Cordinates");

        // Create the first column.
        DataColumn xColumn = new DataColumn();
        xColumn.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.Decimal");
        xColumn.ColumnName = "x";
        xColumn.AutoIncrement = true;
        xColumn.AutoIncrementSeed = startval;
        xColumn.AutoIncrementStep = step;

        // Create the second, calculated, column.
        DataColumn yColumn = new DataColumn();
        yColumn.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.Decimal");
        yColumn.ColumnName = "y";
        yColumn.Expression = func;

        // Add columns to DataTable.
        table.Columns.Add(xColumn);
        table.Columns.Add(yColumn);

        // Once a table has been created, use the
        // NewRow to create a DataRow.
        DataRow row;

        for (int i = 0; i <= 100; i++){
            row = table.NewRow();
            table.Rows.Add(row);
        }

        return table;
    }
```

This of course throws the error:
"System.Data.EvaluateException: 'The expression contains undefined function call sin().'"
Is there any way to use functions like this? And also not as important but is there any way to use a float as your step?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

The functions supported by `DataColumn.Expression` are documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datacolumn.expression?view=net-5.0), and are limited to CONVERT,LEN,ISNULL,IIF,TRIM, and SUBSTRING, along with basic arithmetic.  So unless you want to code a [series expansion of sin](https://www.dummies.com/education/math/calculus/expressing-the-function-sin-x-as-a-series/), you'll have to find another way to acomplish your objective.